# Using a CSS image sprite for hover effect without the scrolling animation

Tags: scroll, css-sprites, background-position

I'm using a sprite image to change the background on hover and click (the .keepImage class is for the click). It all works, but when the background picture changes it scrolls over to the correct position. Is there a way to do it without the scrolling motion?

JS:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a.doing").click(function() { 
                $(this).siblings(".keepImage").removeClass("keepImage");
                $(this).addClass("keepImage");
            });
        });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
a.doing {
            width: 229px;
            height: 202px;
            margin-right: 8px;
            background: url(http://localhost:8000/img/manifesto/spr_doing.png) 0 0;
        }
a.doing:hover, a.doing.keepImage {
            background: url(http://localhost:8000/img/manifesto/spr_doing.png) -229px 0;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, somewhere in your css you have the transition property specified. Usually when you have a transition property specified like this: "transition: all 500ms ease;", the background position will change with a scrolling effect. If you want to prevent this scrolling from happening, then you can either remove the transition property completely, or you can use transition only for the properties you want to animate like - border, color etc.. but not background. If you can somehow provide a link to your page, or give the html mark up and css, it will help. Thanks.